# All Python versions crash after installing 3.6

Tags: python, osx-yosemite

This is related to a mac running 10.10.5.  Trying to install Python 3.6.  Cannot find any answers so far.

Upgraded from python.org, installs correctly (at least that's the indication from the installation sw) but when opening IDLE or running test (`python3.6 -m test`) I get the message: **Python quit unexpectedly**.  Here is a truncated problem report from OS X after attempting to open IDLE:

> ```
>     Process:               Python [1236]
>     Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>     Identifier:            org.python.python
>     Version:               3.6.4 (3.6.4)
>     Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>     Parent Process:        bash [401]
>     Responsible:           Terminal [301]
>     User ID:               501
>
>     Date/Time:             2018-03-08 09:36:59.185 +0100
>     OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F2511)
>     Report Version:        11
>     Anonymous UUID:        8D3C18A4-789C-F7B7-0CAC-4F1FF0BB00E8
>
>
>     Time Awake Since Boot: 1300 seconds
>
>     Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
>     Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>     Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
>     Application Specific Information:
>     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 281'
>     terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException abort() called
> ```

I have tried this with Tcl 8.5.18.0 as recommended on python.org.

I also ran the following `python -m test`, got a number of **Python quit unexpectedly** messages (with reports).  Terminal gave this information after test completion:

> ```
>     381 tests OK.
>
>     2 tests failed:
>         test_calendar test_re
>
>     23 tests skipped:
>         test_asdl_parser test_curses test_dbm_gnu test_devpoll test_epoll
>         test_gdb test_msilib test_ossaudiodev test_smtpnet
>         test_socketserver test_spwd test_startfile test_timeout test_tix
>         test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_urllib2net test_urllibnet
>         test_winconsoleio test_winreg test_winsound test_xmlrpc_net
>         test_zipfile64
>
>     Total duration: 14 min 23 sec
>     Tests result: FAILURE
> ```

I have uninstalled python and reinstalled, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some python os dependencies doesn't work with 3.6

did you try with virtual environment ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "virtual environment". I did also try to install using `brew install python` but this did not work either.  With brewer, I got `Error: The brew link step did not complete successfully`
`The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local`...

Comment: check tuto on pipenv or pew, i think it could help you for this trouble.I'm not experimented enought to tell more about it.

Comment: A short update on the brewer error.  I had to remove a number of python files in /usr/local/bin/. Then could run `brew link python` which at least allowed me to get the correct Python version when using `python --version`.

Comment: After cleaning the /usr/local/bin/ and reinstalling using `brew install python` I can get .py scripts to run from the terminal (`python ~/path/file.py`).  But still IDLE crashes!